# Fancybox 2.0.6 close method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

i have a problem with close method of fancybox v2.0.6

I have in my page this code.

```
<a href="myurl" class="btnslide" id="Imagemulti" title="Aggiungi immagine">Aggiungi immagine</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Imagemulti").fancybox({
        maxWidth: 800,
        maxHeight: 600,
        fitToView: false,
        width: '88%',
        height: '88%',
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        arrows: false,
        type: 'iframe',
        afterClose: function() {
            $('#imgqueue').load('myurl2')
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

When i click on a tag the fancybox popup show mypage, where i have a form; when i submit the form on the popup, i show another form e after, submit it, i will close by this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
parent.$.fancybox.close();
</script>
```

Note: myurl and myurl2 not are variables but link to my site that i have hidden

And it's ok; but if i click again on a tag the popup show the form but on submit the popup don't close. Why? The code is equal. i Don't understend....

It's a fancybox bug?

Thanks for the answers and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Does this - `parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();` work?

Comment: that is not a function, that's the event you want to trigger within a function. Try `function fancyClose(){parent.$.fancybox.close();}` and then call `fancyClose()` when you need it.

Comment: ... or add to the `form` tag the attribute  `onsubmit="parent.$.fancybox.close();"`

Comment: Why my code, first time work and second time not work? It's this that i don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

use onclosed method for close popup

```
 $("#Imagemulti").fancybox({
        maxWidth: 800,
        maxHeight: 600,
        fitToView: false,
        width: '88%',
        height: '88%',
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        arrows: false,
        type: 'iframe',
         'onClosed' : function () { self.parent.location.reload(); }
        }
    });
```

Comment: onClosed method don't exist in fancybox v.2.0.6. I don't must reload the parent window, but i must reload a portion of parent window ( a div with #imgqueue). I have find the problem; if i delete afterClose callbacks the popup close; but i must reload a portion of parent location, How solve this?